# Is STABLE volatility safe for an idempotent data-modifying function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PL/pgSQL function which updates data (`update_data`). Within the context of a transaction this function can be considered idempotent, i.e. the function, if called with the same arguments within the same transaction, will modify data in exactly the same way. The function is effectively a wrapper around multiple upserts. Here is a condensed version of my use case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION top_level() RETURNS void AS $func$
BEGIN
  -- ...
  SELECT update_data(a => p_a, b => p_b) INTO v_a, v_b, v_c;
  PERFORM nested_one_level(/* ... */);
  -- ...
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE FUNCTION nested_one_level() RETURNS void AS $func$
BEGIN
  -- ...
  SELECT update_data(a => p_a, b => p_b) INTO v_a, v_b;
  PERFORM nested_two_levels(/* ... */);
  -- ...
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE FUNCTION nested_two_levels() RETURNS void AS $func$
BEGIN
  -- ...
  SELECT update_data(a => p_a, b => p_b) INTO v_a;
  -- ...
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that within the transaction the function will always be called with the same arguments. However, I am using different `INTO` clauses.

The reason why the `update_data` function is called multiple times is so that some of the nested functions can be used standalone via other RESTful routes.

As I understand it setting `update_data`'s volatility level to `STABLE` will mean (a) we get a potential performance win, and (b) we avoid having to cache the result of `update_data` and pass it around in order to not call it again, e.g.

```
IF p_update_data_results IS NOT NULL THEN
  SELECT update_data(a => p_a, b => p_b) INTO v_a, v_b, v_c;
END IF;
```

I am only hesitant due to the following from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xfunc-volatility.html):

> Any function with side-effects **must** be labeled VOLATILE, so that calls to it cannot be optimized away.

But I would assume that if the side-effects are guaranteed to be the same given the same arguments in the same transaction then the use of `STABLE` is safe?

I'm using Postgres **9.5.4**.

Comment: You should be hesitant instead because *A `STABLE` function cannot modify the database* (from the same docs you linked). -- The reason is simple: `STABLE` functions themselves could not see the results of their own DML statements.

Comment: @pozs thank you - sorry, should have kept reading!